problem assigning elements in integer arrays in c
Im gonna be honest im not really sure what is going on but the issue seems to either be the assigning of the values for the integer array or in my binary conversion code. this is for a school assignment so unfortunatly I am unable to use global variables even though it would make this so much easier.
int binaryConvert(int octet)// this is the binary conversion function. i know its messy
{
    int binaryNum;
    int binaryArr[4][4];
    char binaryString[31];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        while (octet >= 0)
        {
            for (int g = 0; g <= 3; g++)
            {
                binaryArr[i][g] = octet % 2;
                octet = octet / 2;
            }
        }
    }

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        for (int g = 0; g <= 3; g++)
        {
            binaryString[count++] = binaryArr[i][g];
        }
    }

    binaryNum = atoi(binaryString);
    return binaryNum;
}

this is the assignment, when i comment out the code, it seems to work which leads me to believe that it is either the assignment or the binary conversion(which is really messy for no reason at all)
    binary[0] = binaryConvert(octet1);
    binary[1] = binaryConvert(octet2);
    binary[2] = binaryConvert(octet3);
    binary[3] = binaryConvert(octet4);

i havent tried much because i am seriously stuck on this problem. all i have identified is that those two sections of code are the cause of the issue.it should be printing out 120.30.200.50 and then the binary equivilant of those numbers however it just kinda gets stuck and doesnt print anymore

"... so unfortunatly I am unable to use global variables" - I like your teacher already!

Can you give qn example of what arguments you pass to binaryConvert()? The code you show doesn't print anything, so I don't expect any output. It's also not at all clear from the code what you want it to do.

while (octet >= 0) When does octet ever go negative?

Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function main and all #include directives, as well as the exact input required to reproduce the problem (which should preferably be hard-coded into the program). This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Have you tried running your code one line at a time in a debugger while monitoring the control flow and the values of all variables, in order to determine in which line your program stops behaving as intended? If you did not try this, then you may want to read this: What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems? You may also want to read this: How to debug small programs?

@HershJoshi  I perceive "Stackoverflow is intended for more advanced questions rather than learning introductory programming."  as misleading. Even very basic questions are welcome, if they are new and according to [ask]. What is however NOT desired on StackOverflow are answers given in comments instead of according to [answer] in an answer post. If your valid observation might or might not be the actual answer please ask for additional information, e.g. an MRE.

@HershJoshi I realized the issue i made, but maybe you could take into consideration that maybe i just overlooked the problem and wanted some help. no need to phrase your answer so harshly. also i have never asked a question on stack overflow so i was not sure what to add. btw I have been programming for 5+ years, im just working with very little time and overlooked issues.

Mason, I recommend to spend more time on thinking about the other feedback you got. And if you already did and now know the answer, consider creating your own answer according to [answer]. In that case you however probably also want to [edit] your question according to [ask] and according to the feedback you got, e.g. add a [mre] which demonstrates with hardcoded input. If you do that you could end up with a much better experience on your first contribution to StackOveflow. By the way, welcome. Try to select the constructive feedback for bothering, skip the unkind part. (Though some is both.)

You need at least char binaryString[33]; if you're going to store all 32 bits of a 32-bit int and a trailing null. OTOH, if you're really dealing with an octet as the name of the argument suggests, then you only need 9 bytes.  Meanwhile, int binaryArr[4][4]; has space for 16 numbers.  It seems to me that you need to look hard at the problem definition and the sizes of the variables.  Would the code break if you put assert(octet >= 0 && octet <= 255); at the top of the function?

I also don't see any reason to use global variables. Using them would make the code harder to understand.  Global constants might be useful but are not necessary.

It's hard to be sure, but it looks like you're asked to return a number whose significant decimal digits are the same as the significant binary digits of the input.  We see variations on this problem from time to time, and I hate it.  It tends to covey a misleading idea of the computer representation of numbers.  Any props due to the instructor for forbidding use of global variables are forfeited for assigning this particular exercise at all.

How does this function make sense in the first place? It seems you have a binary number and then you want to convert it to a binary number. That doesn't make any sense. Or are you trying to convert it to a decimal number which looks like binary because it only contains digits 1 or 0? Such as int x = 1010;? That's a 100% useless thing to have. Either you have binary numbers which are ideal for the computer, or you have strings representing binary numbers for the benefit of a human viewing the data.
